# Event sourcing and state set event

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm trying out `commanded` framework for Elixir that implements event sourcing and CQRS (it have abstract structure of command, command middleware, router, aggregate, process manager, projection and event handler). I'm listening for changes in `realtime database`. Problem is that when `RTDB` or my service get offline, on reconnect `RTDB` send whole state of table in one request like `{id => data}`.

So I need to detect if some record was not changed or deleted. In mi mind, easiest solution would by to broadcast event to all identities of aggregate (library is splitting every aggregate by identity, and don't allow broadcast to all of them).

One thing is that I need to block all identities of aggregate till they process event from broadcast (I was thinking about bypassing command as event and solve it in saga/process manager or custom handler, but in that case this is not fulfilled)

What would by most idiomatic `event sourcing` solution for this situation?